# Reference a Cell In Excel Based on Criteria in Two Unique Columns

Tags: excel, analytics

I am building a reporting worksheet to track social media data downloaded from Google Analytics.

I have a custom report in analytics that provides me with the date, medium and visits in three unique columns.  I want to extract the number of visits, defined by medium and date, to a separate table where I have other data living.

Here is my source information:

[image: Excel Data Source Example]

Here is my destination:

[image: Excel Data Destination Example]

I want to fill the number of visits from my Twitter data on the other sheet into my destination above while making sure the dates correspond.

Is this possible with Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very much so,

You can use Pivot Tables - which will pretty much take care of it for you via the instructions.  Or if you want a formula based approach:

```
      A               B           C
1 Date            Medium      Visits
2 11/20/2012      Facebook    3
3 11/20/2012      Twitter     5
4 11/19/2012      Facebook    3
5 11/14/2012      Twitter     1
6 11/15/2012      Twitter     4
```

I like to use a function called SumProduct.  It can be slow and bulky, but sometimes its easier than using a VB Macro.

To do this:

```
Total Facebook     xxxx
```

use:

=SumProduct((LookupArea = Condition)*(ColumnTotals))

How it works, is for each cell in your lookup area, it compares it to the condition.  If the condition is true, it creates a (1).  If it is false, it creates a (0).  This is multipled against condition two.  And condition two is telling it to take the "Visits" column and multipy it by an offset of 1 (so, 10 visits x 1 offset, is 10 visits).

Sample:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B6="Facebook")*(C2:C6))
```

This gives the result: 6

You can add even more conditions by adding a * and the next condition

```
=SUMPRODUCT((condition1)*(condition2)*(condition3))
```

You could also come up with a different totals by using +, -, /, etc.  This allows you to negate values.  And you can dual nest values and treat them separately.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((condition1)*(condition2))-(condition3)*(condition4)))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!  I wanted to avoid pivot tables because I am combining the data with other data sources. I have found that Pivot tables are great for reporting but not for creating an actual data set.

I prefer a function based solution.  Your function seems to work if I want to find the total visits from Facebook in the table.  However, I just want to know the visits for a given day, not a total. 

This solution also needs to be flexible as I will be adding more data to this table each week.

Comment: A pivot table would work great with the data as you, or Mario,showed it, but maybe that's not an accurate representation.  As gdoron says, you can extend the Sumproduct and create another condition that multiplies by the date. A web search will get you lots of info about this.